# Visual Studio 2010 Server Explorer Data Connections

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and I'm following this [LINK](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm) but when I reach Step #3 I stuck. How to overcome this problem?. Thanks.

3. Install Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 11.2.0.3 or later from OTN. The ODAC download includes Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and ODP.NET that will be used in this lab.

Comment: @Irb: I try to download this file named ODAC112021Xcopy_32bit from the oracle site. How can I use this?

Comment: After partially reading the article you are attempting to follow it seems the executable only adds Oracle database support for scaffolding and data connections within Visual Studio and is a win32 application.  I have never used these extensions. Does it install?

Comment: @lrb In Server Explorer I don't have the select option of ODP.NET in Oracle Database.